# Expressing a vector space over a finite field as a finite union of proper subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Am trying to solve the following exercise which appeared in an abstract algebra textbook :
Assume that $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over a finite field ${\bf F}_{q}$ which consists of $q$ elements. If $V$ is a finite set theoretic union of $m$ proper linear subspaces ${W_1},\cdots {W_m},$ then it must be the case that $$m\geq{\frac{{q^n}-1}{q-1}}.$$ Prove that there exist ${\frac{{q^n}-1}{q-1}}$ subspaces whose union is $V$.

It is clear that each of the proper subspaces must consist of $q^k$ elements where $k<n$. Not sure how to approach this question!

Comment: This is false as stated.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I stated it exactly as it appeared in the book *A Course in Galois Theory* by D. J. H. Garling. (Exercise 1.18, page 13). After I posted the question, I noticed that it was dropped from a second printing.

Comment: TokenToucan, the argument below shows one can find $\frac {q^n -1} {q-1}$ subspaces whose union is $V$. However, is the inequality $m\geq {\frac {q^n -1} {q-1}}$ not necessarily true?

Comment: Yes, it is the inequality which is not true. In fact, it follows relatively quickly from the example that the inequality is false (see comment below).

Comment: For instance $\Bbb F_2^3$ can be covered by three 2D subspaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the comments, I believe this is true.  There are $q^n-1$ nonzero elements $v$, and each such $v$ is in the one-dimensional subspace $W_v=\{fv|f\in F_q\}.$  Each of these subspaces has $q-1$ nonzero elements, so there are $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$ distinct $W_v$ whose union is $V$.

Comment: So this actually *partitions* $V$ into mutually disjoint subspaces each having cardinality $q-1$.

Comment: I really like this answer. If $k$ is an infinite field and $V$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space, it cannot be the set theoretic union of a finite collection of proper subspaces. The intuitive picture is that no finite collection of lines through the origin of ${\bf R}^2$ can be equal to ${\bf R}^2$ itself-these lines miss the points on the plane between two adjacent lines. This example intuitively underscores that this *can* happen for finite dimensional vector spaces over finite fields.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: @saulspatz The first statement in the question is not true. The particular part you address is true but, in fact, your (correct) example is essentially the reason the inequality can't be true (except in 2 dimensions) because a single two-dimensional subspace can replace some pair of these one-dimensional subspaces (in fact it'll replace more than just two of them).

Comment: I did NOT downvote you saulspatz!!

Comment: AT least I had NO INTENTION of downvoting you! Quite the contrary. I tried upvoting you but it did not let me do so.

Comment: @student I didn't say you downvoted the answer.  I'm sure you didn't.

Comment: @runway44 Yes, I was only focussing on the part that was to be proved.